# When would Jest fail to import package?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, azure-ad-msal

I'm writing a service for performing different MS Graph API requests that hooks in to an already existing React App. To do this I am using the Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL) for authentication. I get the app and the function to run smoothly. The problem is that when I try to run the test suite (Jest) it fails. The test that fails is very basic.

OurComponent/ourComponent.test.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import OurComponent from "./index";

it("renders without crashing", () => {
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  const props = {
    unitId: "1"
  };
  ReactDOM.render(
    <OurComponent {...props}>
      {(state, CompentActions) => {
        return <div />;
      }}
    </OurComponent >,
    div
  );
});
```

My knowledge of Jest is very basic but I gather that it just asserts if the component can mount.

The component imports and uses my function as follows:

OurComponent/index.jsx

```
import * as MyService from "./ServiceFolder/MyService";
/*
Rest of the component
*/
async addData(newData){
  let msg = await MyService.addData(newData);
/*
Rest of the function*/

}
```

And the service looks like this:
OurComponent/ServiceFolder/MyService.jsx

```
import config from "config.js";
import { UserAgentApplication } from "msal";

const userAgentApplication = new UserAgentApplication(config);

export async function addData(newData){
//Do some stuff
}
/*
Rest of the service
*/
```

The error I receive is the following:

```
Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined

      4 | 
    > 5 | const userAgentApplication = new UserAgentApplication(config);
        |                              ^
      6 | 

      at Function.Object.<anonymous>.UrlUtils.getHashFromUrl (node_modules/msal/src/utils/UrlUtils.ts:229:48)
      at Function.Object.<anonymous>.UrlUtils.deserializeHash (node_modules/msal/src/utils/UrlUtils.ts:260:31)
      at Function.Object.<anonymous>.UrlUtils.urlContainsHash (node_modules/msal/src/utils/UrlUtils.ts:245:37)
      at new UserAgentApplication (node_modules/msal/src/UserAgentApplication.ts:240:42)
      at Object.<anonymous> (js/lib/components/OurComponent/ServiceFolder/MyService.jsx:5:30)
      at Object.<anonymous> (js/lib/components/OurComponent/index.jsx:9:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (js/lib/components/OurComponent/ourComponent.test.js:3:1)
```

I'm having a hard time figuring out what would cause this error. Does anyone have any thoughts of what I have missed or hints of how I should proceed?

Comment: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-react

Comment: It looks like there is a problem as jest transplied your library. I can't tell more until I have more info. Is your repo public? Then I can have a look then

Comment: Sadly, the repo isn't public

Comment: I found something interesting https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/deab8d666b50117d5411b6226d8214a35540054e/lib/msal-core/src/UserAgentApplication.ts#L240. It sounds like you have to mock your window location.

Comment: Why don't you just use [`@testing-library/react`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@testing-library/react) like the official CRA does?

Comment: As long as your `jsdom` has an address with a hash value then it would work

Comment: @ChristosLytras With my limited knowledge of Jest I can't say why the tests are set up the way that they are, but I think it would be a bad idea for me to go in and make changes that would affect the whole product. (Classic case of don't fix that which is not broken)

Comment: It expects the environment to behave like a real browser. Node isn't a real browser. Mock this package.

Comment: I agree with you about not breaking things that working though I doubt that this is working as expected without a DOM there... CRA choses to test the App and Components using `@testing-library/react`, see here [cra-template/template/src/App.test.js](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/cra-template/template/src/App.test.js)

Comment: I think the package he's using which is supposed to be tested on browser-like `jsdom` in this case

Comment: If you configure `testEnvironment: node`,  you should switch back to `jsdom` then it would also work I guess

Comment: @tmhao2005 It's already assumed in React tests that jsdom is enabled. It's enabled by default in Jest. It would throw an error if `location` weren't available.

Comment: I tried switching changing the testEnvironment to jsdom, but no changes was observed. I also tried to use the CRA approach with testing-library/react but it didn't affect the outcome either

Comment: Or there was a setup to override the location.href. Try to print out before value `var urlHash = window.location.hash;` at `node_modules/msal/lib-commonjs/UserAgentApplication.js`

Comment: Thanks for your input guys. In the end I settled for just mocking the MSAL constructor which made the tests turn green and I didn't delve much deeper than that.